# XCode 4.02 (4A2002a) encounters internal log error and crashes when I try to create a new file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm using XCode 4.02 (4A2002a) on OS 10.6.8. I can create new projects, and new files in new projects, no problem.

However I get the following error when I try to create a new file in my project. I thought maybe my project file got corrupted somehow so I copied my files into a new project, but I get the same error. Any insight would be appreciated.

ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEKit/IDEKit-303/Framework/Classes/Assistants/IDETemplateInstantiationAssistant.m:47
Details:  Assertion failed: [childItems count] == 1
Object:   
Method:   -workspaceNavigableItem
Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1}

Comment: Xcode 4.0.2 crashes often under various circumstances. For example, try to rename an IBOutlet via the refactoring assistant while a XIB using that IBOutlet is open: guaranteed crash, every time. We can't fix Xcode for you, so you can either try the latest Xcode 4.2 beta and/or submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Thats true, or you can downgrade your xcode to 3.2.6 to check your code.

Comment: 4.1 is alot better, if you are willing to use Lion.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience this is something to do with SVN (or possibly GIT). Try disabling the SVN integration, or at the very least check the settings. At worst case try a fresh working copy.

Answer (score 1):

"Xcode crashes" or "Xcode throws exceptions/assertion failures" can't really be addressed here. [File a bug report with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) as they're the only ones who can fix it.